# MongoDB: why the mongod service is shutdown?

Tags: centos, mongodb

When I use daemon service to start mongodb, MongoDB is always received kill signal by system(CentOS7.3) after about 2 minutes:

Log: [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated)

But when I run it Manually in shell:   /data/mongo/bin/3.4/mongod -f /data/mongo/config/uxdb_27019.conf --fork , it runs ok.

My mongodb daemon service: /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

```
[Unit]
Description=mongodb
After=network.target·
After=syslog.target

[Service]|
Type=forking
User=mongo
ExecStart=/data/mongo/bin/3.4/mongod -f /data/mongo/config/uxdb_27019.conf
PrivateTmp=true
PIDFile=/data/mongo/pid/mongod_27019.pid
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitNOFILE=32000
LimitNPROC=32000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which process is terminate mongod service ?

```
2017-08-08T14:57:55.638+0800 I NETWORK  [conn12] received client metadata from 10.10.9.51:56714 conn12: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3T_5.0.0-74-g1de6631-dirty" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows Server 2012 R2", architecture: "amd64", version: "6.3" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_121-b13" }
2017-08-08T14:59:14.169+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-08-08T14:59:14.169+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
```

Comment: Remove the `--fork` option. That should only be used on command line execution. Using `systemd` it "daemonizes" automatically, so you don't need the option.

Comment: but when I Remove the --fork option, it also shutdown after 2 minutes

Comment: You might also need to run `mongod` under an `strace` to track down where the kill signal is coming from. However the `--fork` option has no place here and should be removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078089/how-to-find-who-send-the-sigterm-signal-to-my-process-or-my-process-group and general usages of  `strace` https://www.google.com/search?q=centos+trace+sigterm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by:

1. Modify the daemon: mongod.service:  from forking to oneshot

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ```
2. Modify config/Mongodb.conf:  remark the follow line:

   ```
   #processManagement:
   #fork: true
   ```

But I don't know why, but it works well now.

Comment: Because your service was exiting after launching your process. Now it will wait until your process exits, and then the service will stop.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the valie of **PIDFile** in your **mongod.service** :

[Service]

... deleted ...

Type=forking

**PIDFile=/data/mongo/pid/mongod_27019.pid**

... deleted ...

Must have the same value with **pidFilePath** in **/etc/mongod.conf**:

processManagement:

fork: true
  **pidFilePath: /data/mongo/pid/mongod_27019.pid**

Hope this can help your problem.

Comment: You saved my nighs! Thank you. That was the reason that systemd killed mongos, but I don't use Type=forking. Anyway PIDFile saved me.